# Como passar um objeto para outra Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

```
    public class Despesa
    {
        private long id ;
        private Date data;
        private String local;
        private String endereco ;
        private String cnpj ;
        private LinkedList <Item> itens;
        private String URL ;

        public void buscarDespesa (Classificacao classificacao)
        { 

        }

        //MAIS OUTROS MÉTODOS


    }

    public class Item
    {
        private int id ;
        private Double preco;
        private String produto;
        private Classificacao classificacao;
        private Despesa despesa ;
        private Boolean isChecked ;
    }

public class Classificacao
{
    private int id ;
    private int cor ;
    private String nome ;
}
```

Considerando os métodos gets e sets e construtor, como faço para passar uma Despesa de uma Activity para outra no Android ?

Comment: Se não for dessa deve ser de alguma outra. Se não for de nenhuma, é uma pergunta bem canônica.